# I want to replace everything between <desc> and </desc> in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find, find-and-replace

I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Had to use .*? and make sure .matches new line was checked.